# Promise is not working in Cron Job in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, es6-promise

Promise is not working inside cronjob in nodejs.

let me explain my question with this code.

I have one cron that running in every five seconds.

Now Inside a cron I have one function **client.statistics** and I think it's take some time. so I need to wait for that and then after below code run.

**Issue:** Issue is I use that code without promise so I know without promise it not worked. now I use promise for wait for that function time but currently not working.

I use promise and now my out like this.

**output**:
--- CRON START ---
DATE-TIME 2021-10-22 11:41:10

**it's not executing below code, don't know what happen here**

**What I need:** I need First Execute **Top Code** then **Promise Code** then **last code** like console like end cron.

**Thank you advanced. :)**

```
const twelvedata = require("twelvedata");

cron.schedule('*/5 * * * * *', () => {
    var today = new Date();
    var datetime = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    console.log('--- CRON START ---');
    console.log('DATE-TIME', datetime);
    let symbol = "5PAISA";
    let params = {
        symbol:symbol,
        exchange: "NSE",
        country: "India",
    };

    let mypromise = function functionOne(){
        const client = twelvedata(config);
        return new Promise((resolve ,reject)=>{
            client.statistics(params).then((data) => {
                console.log("All Worked",data);
                resolve("Resolved");
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error', error);
                reject("Rejected")
            });
        });
    };

    mypromise().then((res)=>{
        console.log(`The function recieved with value ${res}`)
        console.log('--- CRON END ---');
        return datetime;
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(`Handling error as we received ${error}`);
        console.log('ERROR');
        return false;
    });

    console.log('--- CRON FINISHED ---');

});
```

Comment: Can you not change this to use async / await? The Multiple layers of nested function calls that you're using here have increased the cognitive overhead of your code massively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your `new Promise((resolve ,reject)=>{ … })` is an anti-pattern, because inside of that you create a promise chain.

Also `reject("Rejected")` is often considered as an anti-pattern because the `reject("Rejected")` is considered to be equivalent to the meaning of `throw "Rejected"` and you should only throw actual errors.

`console.log('--- CRON FINISHED ---');` does not wait for the promise chain to be finished but is called immediately.

Here a cleaned-up version of your code.

```js
const twelvedata = require("twelvedata");

cron.schedule('*/5 * * * * *', () => {
  var today = new Date();
  var datetime = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  console.log('--- CRON START ---');
  console.log('DATE-TIME', datetime);

  let symbol = "5PAISA";
  let params = {
    symbol: symbol,
    exchange: "NSE",
    country: "India",
  };


  twelvedata(config)
    .statistics(params)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("All Worked", data);
      return "Resolved"
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error', error);
      return "Rejected"
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(`The function recieved with value ${res}`)
      console.log('--- CRON END ---');
      // you don't make use of this returned value in your code ?
      // return datetime;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(`Handling error as we received ${error}`);
      console.log('ERROR');
      // you don't make use of this returned value in your code ?
      // return false;
    })
    .finally(() => {
      console.log('--- CRON FINISHED ---');
    });


});
```

As I said the `reject("Rejected")` is an antipattern and in your case it is not clear why you even translate the actual error to `Rejected` you could just let the error pass through to your `` console.log(`Handling error as we received ${error}`); ``.

```js
const twelvedata = require("twelvedata");

cron.schedule('*/5 * * * * *', () => {
  var today = new Date();
  var datetime = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  console.log('--- CRON START ---');
  console.log('DATE-TIME', datetime);

  let symbol = "5PAISA";
  let params = {
    symbol: symbol,
    exchange: "NSE",
    country: "India",
  };


  twelvedata(config)
    .statistics(params)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("All Worked", data);
      return "Resolved"
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(`The function recieved with value ${res}`)
      console.log('--- CRON END ---');
      return datetime;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(`Handling error as we received ${error}`);
      console.log('ERROR');
      return false;
    })
    .finally(() => {
      console.log('--- CRON FINISHED ---');
    });


});
```

Using `async` and `await` can make the whole thing even more clearer.

```js
const twelvedata = require("twelvedata");

cron.schedule('*/5 * * * * *', async() => {
  var today = new Date();
  var datetime = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  console.log('--- CRON START ---');
  console.log('DATE-TIME', datetime);

  let symbol = "5PAISA";
  let params = {
    symbol: symbol,
    exchange: "NSE",
    country: "India",
  };

  // I commented that out because you acutall don't use that in your code, but is would it shows how to match your `return` statements in the promise chain.
  // let result;  
  try {
    const data = await twelvedata(config).statistics(params)
    console.log("All Worked", data);
    const res = "Resolved"

    // result = datetime;
    console.log(`The function recieved with value ${res}`);
    console.log('--- CRON END ---');
  } catch (error) {
    // result = false;
    console.log(`Handling error as we received ${error}`);
    console.log('ERROR');
  }

  // console.log(result)

  console.log('--- CRON FINISHED ---');

});
```

And removing everything that does not seem to be used:

```js
const twelvedata = require("twelvedata");

cron.schedule('*/5 * * * * *', async() => {
  var today = new Date();
  var datetime = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  console.log('--- CRON START ---');
  console.log('DATE-TIME', datetime);

  let symbol = "5PAISA";
  let params = {
    symbol: symbol,
    exchange: "NSE",
    country: "India",
  };

  try {
    const data = await twelvedata(config).statistics(params)
    console.log("All Worked", data);
    console.log('--- CRON END ---');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Handling error as we received ${error}`);
    console.log('ERROR');
  }


  console.log('--- CRON FINISHED ---');

});
```

Comment: Yeah, It's working thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of returning a new promise in the `functionOne` try to assign a promise to the `mypromise` variable.

```
let mypromise = new Promise((resolve ,reject) => {
                  const client = twelvedata(config);
                  client.statistics(params).then((data) => {
                     console.log("All Worked",data);
                     resolve("Resolved");
                  }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error', error);
                    reject("Rejected")
                 });
               });
```

Now use it without calling:

```
mypromise.then((res)=>{
        console.log(`The function recieved with value ${res}`)
        console.log('--- CRON END ---');
        return datetime;
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(`Handling error as we received ${error}`);
        console.log('ERROR');
        return false;
    }).finally(() => {
        console.log('--- CRON FINISHED ---')
    })
```

Comment: I tried you code, yeah it's working fine but issue is the log I recently added in question please check that. So the console log CRON FINISHED is called first and then call CRON END log. Why it's happen? your solution is almost ok but this last flow like first print CRON END and then CRON FINISHED.

Comment: it's the correct behavior since you are using the asynchronous method. the last `'--- CRON FINISHED ---'` logged first because it's not an async action, then the async parts run. you can fix it with the `finally` method, I've added this requirement to the answer. @DarshanRaval

Comment: It's working with your code also. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

### You don't need your own promise based wrapper API, because the api you're using already returns promises

Consider rewriting the code so you aren't using so many promises and nested callbacks.

This (untested) version of the code has only 2 levels of indentation , no callbacks (ignoring that its all in a call to cron.schedule), and is 6 lines shorter.

```
const twelvedata = require("twelvedata");

cron.schedule('*/5 * * * * *', async () => {
    try
    {
        var today = new Date();
        var datetime = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        console.log('--- CRON START ---');
        console.log('DATE-TIME', datetime);
        let symbol = "5PAISA";
        let params = {
            symbol:symbol,
            exchange: "NSE",
            country: "India",
        };
    
        const client = twelvedata(config);
        const data = await client.statistics(params);
        console.log(`The function recieved with value ${data}`)
        console.log('--- CRON END ---');
        return datetime;
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        console.log(`Handling error as we received ${error}`);
        console.log('ERROR');
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        console.log('--- CRON FINISHED ---');
    }

});
```